# Programming PLTW robot with claw

Tags: java

```
if(SensorValue (bumpswitch)==1)
{
    startMotor(WheelMotor2,-20);
}
if(SensorValue (bumpswitch2)==1)
{
    startMotor(WheelMotor2,20);
}
if(SensorValue(bumpswitch3)==1)
{
    startMotor(LiftMotor,30);
}
if(SensorValue(bumpswitch3)==0)
{
    stopMotor(LiftMotor);
}
if (SensorValue(bumpswitch4)==1)
{
    startMotor(TopMotor,120);
}
```

}
How do we get all of these motors to move with one bump switch? Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: If `bumpswitch == bumpswitch2 == 1`, what should happen?

Comment: The motor should move the claw

Comment: But then you have `WheelMotor1` moving at `20` and `-20` at the same time?

Comment: Ya, so is there a better way to code this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that cause the motor to break? Or is that the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: your wrong but we figured it out, thanks.

Comment: This question is rather unclear. Does this code work already?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing the `else` keyword.

To explain, here's a bit of code similar to yours:

```
if (condition1) {action1;}
if (condition2) {action2;}
```

If both are true, both are executed. This means that if both `bumpswitch` and `bumpswitch2` have value `1`, then the code will first spin the motor at `20` and then immediately change it to `-20`.

```
if (condition1) {action1;}
else if (condition2) {action2;}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if (condition1) {
    action1;
} else {
    if (condition2) {
        action2;
    }
}
```

If `condition1` is satisfied, then it will run the first part (`action1`). If it is not satisfied, and `condition2` is satisfied, then it will run the second part. So:

if (SensorValue(bumpswitch) == 1) {
    startMotor(WheelMotor2, -20);
} else if (SensorValue(bumpswitch2) == 1) {
    startMotor(WheelMotor2, 20);
}

will fix the first issue.

Now, as for a better way to code this, there isn't really much to improve on. If you want more tips on making your code better, you may want to check out [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Your final code should look like this:

```
if (SensorValue(bumpswitch) == 1) {
    startMotor(WheelMotor2, -20);
} else if (SensorValue(bumpswitch2) == 1) {
    startMotor(WheelMotor2, 20);
}

if (SensorValue(bumpswitch3) == 1) {
    startMotor(LiftMotor, 30);
} else if (SensorValue(bumpswitch3) == 0) {
    stopMotor(LiftMotor);
}

if (SensorValue(bumpswitch4) == 1) {
    startMotor(TopMotor, 120);
}
```

Note that they're not all `else if` blocks, because otherwise only one action could be executed.

Alternatively, if the issue is that the motors are starting one by one, then this should work:

```
if (SensorValue(bumpswitch) == 1) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            startMotor(WheelMotor2, -20);
        }
    }).start();
} else if (SensorValue(bumpswitch2) == 1) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            startMotor(WheelMotor2, 20);
        }
    }).start();
}

if (SensorValue(bumpswitch3) == 1) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            startMotor(liftMotor, 30);
        }
    }).start();
} else if (SensorValue(bumpswitch3) == 0) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            stopMotor(liftMotor);
        }
    }).start();
}

if (SensorValue(bumpswitch4) == 1) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            startMotor(TopMotor, 120);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This starts a new thread for each action so they run in parallel.

`else if (SensorValue(bumpswitch3) == 0)` can be replaced with `else` if the sensor value has to be either 1 or 0, because `if (c1) {a1;} else {a2;}` will run `a1` if `c1`, and otherwise and only otherwise, `a2`.